# Diferencia entre Clase<?> y Clase en Java

Tags: java, clase, genericos

entiendo la diferencia entre poner `NombrePila<?>` y `NombrePila<E>`, pudiendo en la primera ser la pila formada por diferentes tipos de objetos y en la segunda solo de un tipo toda la pila. Lo que no entiendo es cual es la diferencia entre especificar `<?>` o no poner nada. no se supone que al no especificar con nada de que tipo es la clase ya es generica?
Gracias!

Comment: ¿Probaste agregar objetos a una pila declarada como `NombrePila<?>`? Si está programada como pienso (como lo está `Stack`) no creo que puedas.

Comment: [Respondido aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6008246/5587982) con bastante claridad.

Comment: @rascadux podrías agregar un ejemplo de **no poner nada**